# How process loaded into memory?

Tags: memory, operating-systems

Suppose I have a file which I want to read in word. When I double click that file some address will be produce that's point to the physical location of that file in hard disk. What is that address called. Is it virtual address or logical address. Where that address resides?

1. Virtual Memory (RAM + Page File)
2. Secondary Memory (Hard Disk)

Comment: Are you asking about the .doc file or about word.exe?

Comment: Your use of terminology is incorrect.  You don't *"load a process into memory"*.  A program (or data) can be loaded into memory.  A process is started/created to execute that program.  A filesystem address is what *"point[s] to the physical location of that file in hard disk"*, which would be an allocation unit (aka cluster) which translates to a Logical Block Address (aka LBA).

Comment: The problem here is that you are confusing programs that use virtual memory and their data that resides on disk. Data on disk is loaded *by* a program and ends up in the virtual memory space, but as data on disk it has no concept of virtual memory. On disk it is simply "blocks of disk". Disk has nothing to do with the address space of a system, it is nothing more than a block based storage system.

Answer (score -2):

Usually, and it should be the case for an office application, the virtual memory is not aware of the origin of file data.

The application allocate physical memory, and read the file using the allocated physical memory.

Comment: This is a simplification that very much ignores the memory mapped file mechanisms used by modern windows.

Comment: Applications also never allocate physical memory in modern systems, they simply allocate memory from the operating system. The operating system gives them a virtual address within that processes address space and from there establishes whether to allocate physical memory based on whether it needs to be immediately filled or not. A memory allocation by a program may never actually hit physical memory if the application simply overallocated a buffer it never actually uses.